# How to open "Set as" menu when setting a wallpaper in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am building  a wallpaper app in java. When user selects an image, a small default menu should pop up like in the provided screenshot, where user can select which app should set the wallpaper.

So far I used WallpaperManager for setting the wallpaper but that doesnt give user an option to move the image etc. This is my first android app ever so I am learning with every step I take, so sorry if this is an easy task. I also have not found SO question that solves my problem.

Can you please point me to the right direction, waht should I google, look for, or show me some code that does this? Thank you in advance.

[image: ref screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the followin code my solve your problem

`File f=new File("wallpaper_file_path");
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER,Uri.fromFile(f));
        startActivity(i);`

Comment: It gives me this error at the line with startActivity(i): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Comment: Ok, so I got the menu to pop up but it says that no apps can perform this action. Can the problem be that I used bitmap instead of a file? The uri I passed to the intent is from a Bitmap to uri converter from [this](https://freakycoder.com/android-notes-72-how-to-convert-bitmap-to-uri-e535391ebdac) guide.

Comment: `Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER);
        startActivity(in);`       ACTIOON_SET_WALLPAPER dosen't take any input use above code

Comment: and how do I attach the image to it now?

Answer (score 0):

I made a wallpaper app, in that, I used a zoom image library so that I can adjust the image then I take the cache of that image view are and set it as wallpaper. and I can set it for the home screen, lock screen and for both

```
 public void SetHomeAndLockScreen()
{


    bmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();//get the cache from zoomable imageview

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    try {
        wpm.setBitmap(bmap, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
        wpm.setBitmap(bmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper Applied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was understand that you need to crop image from gallery try this                           use phone screen width for  x and screen height for y

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");  
intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");  
File file = new File(filePath);  
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);  
intent.setData(uri);  
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");  
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 4);  
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 16);  
intent.putExtra("outputX", 720);  
intent.putExtra("outputY", 1080);  
intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);  
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);                                  
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CROP_ICON);`
```

When the picture select Activity return will be selected to save the contents.in 
    onActivityResult:

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();  
if(extras != null ) {  
Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");  
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, stream);  
    // The stream to write to a file or directly using the photo
}                                                                                                                                                             and set the wall paper using wallpaper manager
```

Comment: Please don't post 2 answers to the same question - edit your answer and merge it with your second answer.

Comment: But dont I need a fileprovider for a URI from file?

Answer (score 0):

Modern solution :)

```
/**
 * Set as wallpaper method
 */
public void setWallpaper() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // Android 7.0+ required
    Uri wallUri = getImageUri(this, wallpaperDrawableBitmap);
    intent.setDataAndType(wallUri, "image/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
    this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));
}
```

Modern solution for static contexts :)

```
/**
 * Set as wallpaper
 */
public static void setWallpaper(Activity activity) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // Android 7.0+ required
    Uri wallUri = getImageUri(activity, wallpaperDrawableBitmapStatic);
    intent.setDataAndType(wallUri, "image/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));
}
```

Note that **setDataAndType(...)** requires the image **URI**.